# Json returning string in wrong format

Tags: model-view-controller

```
public ActionResult BusinessUnitNameSelect(BusinessUnitDTO business)
    {
        BOSetup setup = new BOSetup();
       string newBusiness = setup.BusinessUnitNameSelect(business);
        return Json(newBusiness, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Json returning string in this format. any solution to get string from json in actual format? Actual format is

General

```
      {0: "G", 1: "e", 2: "n", 3: "e", 4: "r", 5: "a", 6: "l", $promise: Promise, $resolved: true}
```